# Backbone.js Post 500 Error

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

**Does anyone know how to specify the ContentType of the Post to json/application?** I thought I was, and backbone did it by default, but judging by the fact it's saying it's getting plain text (see comments), I guess I need to figure out another way to specify it.

I am using Backbone.js and I am trying to POST to the TastyPie API that is no longer read only and I am receiving a 500 error when I try to make a model and .save() it.  This is a code snippet I am using for my sync that i found here: 
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-124

```
   Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options){
        var type = methodMap[method];
        var params = _.extend({
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json'
        }, options);

        if (!params.url){
        params.url = getUrl(model) || urlError();
        }

        if (Backbone.emulateJSON){
        params.contentType = 'application/json';
        params.data = params.data ? {model: params.data} : {};
        }

        if (Backbone.emulateHTTP){
        if(type === 'PUT' || type === 'DELETE'){
           if (Backbone.emulateJSON) params.data._method = type;
           params.type = 'POST';
           params.beforeSend = function (xhr){
               xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', type);
            };
         }
         }

        if (params.type !== 'GET' && ! Backbone.emulateJSON){
        params.prorcessData = false;
        }

        return $.ajax(params);
        };





    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
        });
        return o;
    };

    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
        var dict = $('form').serializeObject();
        var new_task = new Backbone.Model({
        date: toString(dict.date),
        name: toString(dict.name),
        priority: toString(dict.priority)});
        console.log("new_task =" + new_task);
         new_task.save();
        console.log(dict);

        return false;
        });

    });


    });
```

Comment: that's the "regular" backbone.sync right? what 500 response do you get? i recently made an app combining tastypie with backbone. you can check it out here: https://github.com/c4urself/ratebeer maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Comment: : "The format indicated 'text/plain' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on your Serializer.",

Comment: One obstacle here is that, though Paul's solution is correct, Tastypie does not yet support X-HTTP-Method-Override headers.  You could use something like this to add, or directly extend the Resource class you're using with the overridden method: https://gist.github.com/2161338

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` in your code.

If this is set to true, then it sets the `contentType` to 'application/json' which is what you're looking for.

You only need to set this variable once, so a good place is right above your form submit code

```
$(function() {
    Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
    $('form').submit(function() {
        ...
```